# io-ts Object Typename is lost in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I would like to use io-ts in order to validate input.
However compared to an interface type the WebStorm/IDEA does not show the name of the object type when hovered over the type but shows the details of the type itself.

Lets assume we have the following code a io-ts User and a Interface User.

```js
import * as t from 'io-ts';

const UserType = t.type({
    name: t.string,
});

type User = t.TypeOf<typeof UserType>;

interface UserI {
    name: string;
}
const myUserI: UserI = { name: 'Paul' }; //WebStorm Type const myUserI: UserI
const myUserIoTs: User = { name: 'Luna' }; //WebStorm Type const myUserIoTs: { name : string }
```

When I hover over myUserI the type information show from WebStorm is `const myUserI: UserI`

[image: Object Typename Interface]

However when I hover over the myUserIoTs type the information show from WebStorm is `const myUserIoTs: {name: string;}` instead of `const myUserIoTs:User`

[image: Object Typename io-ts]

Is there a way that WebStorm can show the type name `User` instead of `{name: string}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooltip you see in WebStorm when you `ctrl`+ hover over a symbol in a TypeScript file shows the inferred type info from the TypeScript compiler service.
And there's indeed a known difference in the information TypeScript itself provides for interfaces and enums vs type aliases. Here's an issue on the TypeScript's tracker: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25894

Comment: Hi Lena. Thanks a lot for your reply. When I read through the issue you linked I kind of feel that they have the opposite problem, that they want extened type information. Are you sure this is related.

Comment: yes, I'm sure. Though they do indeed want to see extended info for interfaces, just as for type aliases, it's still the same issue, and this is the way tsserver works

Answer (score 0):

There is a workarround for this by defining an interface.

```
interface User extends t.TypeOf<typeof User> {}
```